# How do you solve $-x + 1 < 4x + 5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Been trying to solve this but getting a bit confused. Whats the procedure? Thank you for any help given.

Comment: Collect like terms.

Answer (score 2):

Solving inequalities uses the same procedure as solving equations. You just have to be aware of the fact that dividing/multiplying by a negative number flips the relation, e.g.

$1 < 4 \implies -1 > -4$.

So in your example:

\begin{align*} &-x + 1 < 4x + 5 \\
\iff &-x - 4 < 4x \\
\iff & -4 < 5x \\
\iff & \ldots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

By adding $x$ on both sides we obtain
$$1<5x+5$$
from here we get
$$-4<5x$$
dividing by $5$ we obtain
$$-\frac{4}{5}<x$$